# How do I bake a texture onto another mesh with different UV

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, transparency, texture-baking

[image]

I'm trying to use the texture of the shirt on the right which has a repeating texture and paste it onto the shirt on the left which has no repeating textures and uses a different unwrap process. They have the same geometry but the one on the left is the one that I want to be able to use. Unfortunately, whenever I use the bake texture feature on the very right of the image, the shirt appears all black and has a tiny sliver of shirt texture that you can see on the side of the black shirt.
[image]

This is the UV map of the black shirt. For some reason, when I bake the textures, it makes everything transparent and adds little bits of the shirt to the texture.

Here is the blend file:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To bake the texture, both models must be in the same location and the *Image Texture* node in the target's material must be selected so Blender knows where to bake the image.

[image: before baking]

After the baking process, you can place the models side by side and connect the baked image texture to the *Principled BSDF* in the target model's material to check the result.

[image: after baking]

Your models only have one UV map but if you have models with multiple UV maps you can add a *UV Map* node in the *Shader Editor*, connect it to the target *Image Texture* node, and select the correct UV map for the bake.